# Best way to scale multiple buttons in container

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my website keyboard scalable on mobile devices. I was using @media before but since I'm limited on what I can actually test it I want to make sure I can cover majority of it. I'm currently using Bootstrap for the image I have but I couldn't really find something in the tutorial to really use for a group of buttons.

```
<div id="keyboard">
<div class="keyboardRow">
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">A</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">E</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">I</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">O</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">U</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">P</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">H</button>
</div>
<div class="keyboardRow">
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">G</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">R</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">T</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">K</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">M</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">N</button>
    <button id="keyboardKey" class="keyboardKey">W</button>
</div>

<div class="keyboardRow">
    <button id="buttonHint">Hint</button>
    <button id="buttonQuit">Quit</button>
</div>
```

```
#keyboard {
    font-size: 16pt;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.keyboardRow {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#keyboardKey {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-left: 5pt;
    font-size: 16pt;
    width: 70pt;
}
```

Comment: so you need a way to scale the individual key widths responsively?

Comment: You have invalid markup.  You're missing a closing div tag.  Please update the question to accurately reflect your code.

Comment: @Jesse well all the keys, either individually or using the keyboard container. When I was using media I was having issues with font sizing and I cant exactly test multiple devices. And the chrome mobile view isnt 100% accurate

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: The single letter keyboard keys will be adjusted at the same width and height, and the hint and quit button have there own separate id's anyway @j08691

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called a 'button group' [here is the link to bootstrap's page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) on them.

Answer (score 0):

If it's responsive widths for the keyboard keys, you can try using `vw` property along with `min-width` and `max-width`

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xj3uqh7h/

**CSS**

```
#keyboard {
    font-size: 16pt;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.keyboardRow {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#keyboardKey {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-left: 5pt;
    font-size: 16pt;
    max-width:50px;
    min-width:28px;
    width: 7vw;
}
```